# How to remove elements in a list by a sublist?

Tags: r, list, extract

I have two list a and another sub list which is b:

```
a <- list(c("aa","bb","cc"), c("a","b","c","d","e"))
b <- list(c("aa","cc"),c("a","b","c"))
```

I'd like to extract b from a and result should looks like

```
list(c("bb"), c("d","e")
```

I have tried:

```
1) Map(`[`, a, b)

2) map2(a, b, `[`)

3) sapply(names(a), function(x) a[[x]][,b[[x]], drop = FALSE])
```

But non of them works. I appreciate your help and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Map(function(x, y) x[!x %in% y], a, b)

[[1]]
[1] "bb"

[[2]]
[1] "d" "e"
```

Comment: it gave me this error when I run it on my data:Error in `[.data.table`(x, !x %in% y) : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 6 but there are 2515 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.
Called from: `[.data.table`(x, !x %in% y)

Comment: Don't understand where data.table comes from, in your example you've got lists. Can you amend your example to reflect your real data?

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to use `setdiff` with `Map`

```
Map(setdiff, a, b)
#[[1]]
#[1] "bb"

#[[2]]
#[1] "d" "e"
```

---

Or the similar option in `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(a, b, setdiff)
```

---

Regarding the use of `names` to loop, if we check the `names(a)` or `names(b)`, it is `NULL`

```
names(a)
#NULL
```

because the names were not set.  When creating the `list`, it   can be done with

```
a1 <- list(v1 = c("aa","bb","cc"), v2 = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
```

or after the `list` is created.  can set the names with

```
names(a1) <- c("v1", "v2")
```

or while creating the list, use `setNames`

```
a1 <- setNames(list(c("aa","bb","cc"), c("a","b","c","d","e")), c("v1", "v2"))
```

if the `names` are `NULL`, looping through `NULL` will fail anyway.  An option that is more better is to loop through the numeric index or sequence of `list`.  We don't have to worry about whether the names are set or not.

```
lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) setdiff(a[[i]], b[[i]]))
```